# Microsoft MVC4 ~ Expansion is inconsistent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, root, tilde

In MVC, the ~ at the top of a server side directory reference should be converted to the root of the website.

I have the following lines at the top of my cshtml file:

```
<link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="~/codebase/dhtmlxgrid.css">
<script src="~/codebase/dhtmlxcommon.js"></script>
<script src="~/codebase/dhtmlxgrid.js"></script>
<script src="~/codebase/dhtmlxgridcell.js"></script>
<script src ="~/IactexScripts/WorkOrderAdd.js"></script>
```

When the code is run, I get the following in my output sent to the browser:

```
<link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="/codebase/dhtmlxgrid.css">
<script src="/codebase/dhtmlxcommon.js"></script>
<script src="/codebase/dhtmlxgrid.js"></script>
<script src="/codebase/dhtmlxgridcell.js"></script>
<script src ="~/IactexScripts/WorkOrderAdd.js"></script>
```

Notice that the ~ was properly translated to nothing, since this was running at the root, while on the last line, it was not translated, and as a result, the file was not found.

This is important since this page will not always run from the root of the website.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it to do with the extra space in `src ="~...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tereško is right!  The leading space was the cause of the failure.  Thanks so much!